# database driver class name linked with the jar file

Tags: database, driver

I've got a driver class name and its version numbers .eg oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver and its minor and major version. I've also got multiple driver jar files eg. ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar and ojdbc7.jar.
My app selects a particular driver class name and its version number and loads the driver. Now, to load the a particular driver I need find the particular driver jar file and load it. But, my question is give the driver class name and its major and minor version , how do i select the appropriate driver jar file programmatically.

Comment: What code have you tried to this point? These types of questions can be challenging to answer without knowing where you are.

Comment: I'm using ServiceLoader to load the driver from a directory outside of classpath. But, the ServiceLoader also loads the driver which it finds in the classpath too. So, it is difficult to determine which driver is getting loaded from the driver jar in the directory.